# the best way to change array in object to other obejct attr

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have an Array whith Object like this:

```html
[
  {
    "position": "1",
    "name": "FC Barcelona",
    "data": [
      "91",
      "38",
      "29",
      "4",
      "5",
      "112",
      "29"
    ]
  },
  {
    "position": "2",
    "name": "Real Madrid",
    "data": [
      "90",
      "38",
      "28",
      "6",
      "4",
      "110",
      "34"
    ]
  },
  {
    "position": "3",
    "name": "Atlético Madrid",
    "data": [
      "88",
      "38",
      "28",
      "4",
      "6",
      "63",
      "18"
    ]
  }
]
```

and I want's to convert that to this in nodeJS backend in facet I want's to use vanilla javascript to convert :

```html
[
  {
    "position": "1",
    "name": "FC Barcelona",
    "PTS": "91",
    "Pld" "38",
    "W": "29",
    "D": "4",
    "L": "5",
    "GF": "112",
    "GA": "29"
  },
  {
    "position": "2",
    "name": "Real Madrid",
    "PTS": "90",
    "Pld" "38",
    "W": "28",
    "D": "6",
    "L": "4",
    "GF": "110",
    "GA": "34"
  },
  {
    "position": "3",
    "name": "Atlético Madrid",
    "PTS": "88",
    "Pld" "38",
    "W": "28",
    "D": "4",
    "L": "6",
    "GF": "63",
    "GA": "18"
  }
]
```

I want's to get the data array of any object in my master array and converted the any child of data array to child of the it's own object with the specific key i add to up code

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: I want's to convert the above array to the second one?? It's hard to understand ?

Comment: I understand what you want to do but giving you an answer isn't going to be a beneficial to you than helping you understand where you was going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `forEach`

```js
var ar = [{"position":"1","name":"FC Barcelona","data":["91","38","29","4","5","112","29"]},{"position":"2","name":"Real Madrid","data":["90","38","28","6","4","110","34"]},{"position":"3","name":"Atlético Madrid","data":["88","38","28","4","6","63","18"]}],
  result = [];

ar.forEach(function(e) {
  result.push({
    position: e.position,
    name: e.name,
    PT: e.data[0],
    Pld: e.data[1],
    W: e.data[2],
    D: e.data[3],
    L: e.data[4],
    GF: e.data[5],
    GA: e.data[6]
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, But I think you want to add up everything in data and assign it to it's own object in a different array?

If so, [this](https://gist.github.com/OscarOrSomething/8a36ab99411d76ed0f8ef467021dbb95) might do what you want.

Example output (With your data set):

```
[ { position: '1', name: 'FC Barcelona', sum: 308 },                                                                                                            
{ position: '2', name: 'Real Madrid', sum: 310 },                                                                                                             
{ position: '3', name: 'Atlético Madrid', sum: 245 } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to achieve this with `map`

```
var ar = [{"position":"1","name":"FC Barcelona","data":["91","38","29","4","5","112","29"]},{"position":"2","name":"Real Madrid","data":["90","38","28","6","4","110","34"]},{"position":"3","name":"Atlético Madrid","data":["88","38","28","4","6","63","18"]}],

var result = ar.map(function(e) {
  return{
    position: e.position,
    name: e.name,
    PT: e.data[0],
    Pld: e.data[1],
    W: e.data[2],
    D: e.data[3],
    L: e.data[4],
    GF: e.data[5],
    GA: e.data[6]
  };
});

console.log(result)
```